# Ionic Framework different databases

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic, currently learning to develop using Ionic. I just have a question, I don't know if it is possible.

My plan is to create an Ionic app, one application/code base only, for browser as admin, and mobile app for the user. I will limit their access based on the user.

Is it possible that I have two different database on my app?

- On my browser I will use REST API to connect to MySQL.
- On the generated mobile app, I will use an offline database.

Hope you can enlighten me. The goal is to develop a one application for web and mobile app. But I don't know if it is possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is possible. using SQLite plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, I will try to answer according to what I understood.

You didn't mention the back-end, so I am assuming you are using the same data structure for both, e.g(user has id and name and phone, in both, identically)
In this case you can create a setting file where you will save your constant connection strings along with any necessary information(create a *any-name*.ts file in your root folder and just write down

```
export let example = {...}
```

and whenever you need, just import your *any-name*.ts and use the object inside.

If the data structure is also different, I thinks you will be doing massive works to maintain such an app, but the idea would be creating 2 of each functionalities having the same output but different inputs.

P.S in both cases I mentioned you will need to detect the platform to define which function/information is adequate.